# Koala app how to compile compass with susy?

Tags: sass, compass, koala, susy

I'd like to know how can I compile compass with susy project in [Koala app](http://koala-app.com/). I get following error message:

```
LoadError on line ["45"] of C:cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

My config.rb (it was made via command line):

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'susy'

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed
output_style = :expanded

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
```

Koala app:

Auto Compile
SASS default options: Compass Mode, Autoprefix.
Output style: nested

Answer (score 0):

Use the following 2 commands in your command prompt if you haven't already:

```
gem install compass
```

after a few seconds it should respond telling you 1 gem successfully installed. If it was successful, then type in the following:

```
gem install susy
```

As above it should tell you 1 gem installed. If these installed correctly, go back to your Koala app and go to the main settings menu and select

**Sass > Advanced Settings**

Tick the option for *'Use the system Sass compiler'*, leave the path as is.
Then click on Compass settings turn on *'Use the system Compass Compiler'*, again leave the path as is.

You may need to refresh your project in Koala.

Open up your config.rb file and add the following just under the first line:

```
require 'susy'
```

and save it. Now in your Sass file add the following up top:

```
@import "susy";
```

and you should be good to go! Try adding something simple and see if it compiles.

Comment: Hi, I installed the gems and got this error : "LoadError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace"